# OpenModelica Fortran based External Function read\write error

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to add an external FORTRAN Code to OpenModelica 1.13.0. My function and model definitions are correct and the FORTRAN code normally works. But whenever I add a write(*,*) or read(*,*) method to the code I get the following error as OpenModelica Simulation output:

`undefined reference to _gfortran_transfer_real_write@@GFORTRAN_1.4`

I wonder how can I solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (probably) happens because you are not linking gfortran with the simulation. If the library is shared (so, DLL, dylib), the dependency is usually handled automatically, so you are probably trying to link a static library (.a) or object file (.o, .obj).

In your external function, add an annotation `Library="gfortran"` or since you probably already have your library in there, `Library={"mylib", "gfortran"}`.

Also note that OpenModelica 1.13 is getting old and should be upgraded.

Comment: Same applies here as adding gfortran in the Library requires the actual gfortran to be available in Recources/Library or any directory that Modelica searches for appropriate libraries. I actually have tried your solution before and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For OMShell one can call the setCFlags("-lgfortran") or inside OMEdit add -lgfortran  at Simulation Setup > General > C/C++ Compiler Flags. It will solve the issue.

Comment: It would not solve the issue for someone else using the same Modelica library as they would need to add the flag manually. With the Library annotation, it should work in OpenModelica and other tools for anyone using the model (provided the correct gfortran is available on the linker path).

Comment: The problem is that gfortran is not always available in the linker path. I guess It is possible to modify the source so that it always adds the gfortran link while compiling but so far only this method worked for me.

Comment: It should be available if adding -lgfortran works. OpenModelica may not find it, but the linking should work even if there are warnings

Comment: ok thank you I'll check if it works again.